# Can't bind object to directive scope from another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have started to use directives with ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('book', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/:book',
    template: '<book-tabs />'
  })
  .state('book.about', {
    url: '',
    template: '<book-about />'
  })
  .state('book.stats', {
    url: '/statistics',
    template: '<book-stats />'
  });
```

Here is one of the directives:

```
  export default function(app) {
    app.directive('bookStats', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAs: 'statsTab',
        templateUrl: 'book-stats.tpl.html',
        controller: 'BookStatsCtrl'
      };
    });
  };
```

Inside of `book-stats` directive I want to call `stats-list` directive and pass `book` object.

```
<stats-list review="statsTab.book"></stats-list>
```

And here is `stats-list` directive:

```
export default function(app) {
  app.directive('statsList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        book: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'stats-list.tpl.html',
      controller: 'CircleRankListCtrl'
    };
  });
};
```

**The problem is that `$scope.book` is `undefined` in `stats-list` directive even though that `statsTab.book` not `undefined` in `book-stats` directive.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have change this `review="statsTab.book"` into this `book="statsTab.book"`